# Take one argument from user and set argument as default then run python code with one click

Tags: python-3.x

my code run in terminal as shown i want to take the image from the user then all argument added automatically and the code run.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
python3 recognize.py --detector face_detection_model
    --embedding-model openface_nn4.small2.v1.t7
    --recognizer output/recognizer.pickle
    --le output/le.pickle
    --image IMG_26.JPG
```

we assumed that IMG_26.JPG taken from the user

```sh
python3 recognize.py --detector face_detection_model \
    --embedding-model openface_nn4.small2.v1.t7 \
    --recognizer output/recognizer.pickle \
    --le output/le.pickle \
    --image (image name)
```

Comment: I am confused. Do you have any code?  Do you just want default arguments for if the user doesn't provide some?

Comment: ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
 help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-d", "--detector", required=True,
 help="path to OpenCV's deep learning face detector")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--embedding-model", required=True,
 help="path to OpenCV's deep learning face embedding model")

ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
 help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")

Comment: Please put this in the question not the comments...